# Empty log file when log4j2.xml is outside the jar

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

When log4j2.xml is in the jar (in resources), then everything works. But when I moved log4j2.xml outside the jar, then log file is created but it's empty all the time. I run my application in that way:

```
java.exe -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dlog4j.configurationFile=C:\config\log4j2.xml -jar C:\app\myApp.jar
```

Here is my log4j2.xml file:

```
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
    </Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
    </Console>

    <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
    <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="logs/application.log"
                 filePattern="logs/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the URI: `file://c:/config/log4j2.xml`